# You must let us know whether your app is a COVID-19 contact tracing or status app on App on Play Store

Tags: google-play, store, google-play-console

I want to publish the app to Play Store. But when reviewing the release I got an error like this. But there is no solution or documentation to read more about the error.

[image]

Comment: Don't you just love when Google does this? I had the same problem and couldn't find any solution. Thanks to marcinpl87!!!

Comment: yep, Google did it again! They never fail to mess with developers with new changes they bring. Classic Google!

Comment: I can't believe there's no link in the error message to tell us where to set up it... I was so lost when I encountered it..

Answer (score 102, accepted):

1. Click on <kbd>Policy</kbd> -> <kbd>App content</kbd> in the Google Play Console (at the bottom of the left menu).
2. In your browser, you should have a URL like:

   ```
   https://play.google.com/console/u/0/developers/.../app/.../app-content/summary
   ```
3. Remove `summary` from the URL, and paste `regulated-health-apps`  instead.
4. You should see a form like:

   [image: Form]
5. Select the appropriate checkbox(es), save that form, and publish your app again.

Comment: Today I just needed to click on Policy...App Content in the bottom left. There was a section at the bottom for COVID-19 contact tracing and status apps that needed to be filled in.

Answer (score 10):

On Play console, We require to declare that whether our app is related to Covid-19 or not.

**[Official Guide](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9889712?hl=en)**

Go to the [**App content**](https://play.google.com/console/app/app-content/summary) page **(Policy > App content)** in Play Console, and provide the required information in the "**COVID-19 contact tracing and status apps**" section.

[image]

Comment: This should be an accepted answer.

Answer (score 5):

Click on the "App Content" link in the Google Play console.

Click on COVID-19 contact tracing and status apps

[image]

Select the third and last option and then click on "Save" at the bottom right corner.

[image]