# publish app on google store : covid19 option problem

Tags: android, google-play

i try to publish my application on google store but i've got an error :
"You must let us know whether your app is a COVID-19 contact tracing or status app."
i don't know where can i find this option
thanks

Comment: What kind of app it is?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Comment: Please find the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68819637/you-must-let-us-know-whether-your-app-is-a-covid-19-contact-tracing-or-status-ap

Comment: look this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68819637/you-must-let-us-know-whether-your-app-is-a-covid-19-contact-tracing-or-status-ap